# Failed release upgrade - strange recovered situation

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, grub2, upgrade, kernel

Let's be honest, I am an beginner regarding Ubuntu and I **** up so I reach out to this community to hopefully get more information how to solve the in my opinion impossible situation I created.

I did a do-release-upgrade, from Xenial to Bionic. So far so good, but for reasons which are no excuse I accidentally terminated this upgrade halfway and came into the situation that trying to resume this process that I either needed to reboot or skip the whole process. You already can guess the outcome, choose wrong, server totally useless .....

The provider of this server managed to get this thing up and running again, but now I have the following situation:

1. The server boots on the 2nd kernel, which is as I understand Bionic. How this is possible is a mystery to me. I was halfway this upgrade (2 hours, comparing some xrdp configuration) so I think this Bionic needs a lots of repair.
   But this booting on 2nd kernel setting still needs to be permanently set. I think that this is possible using GRUB commands, but I am not totally sure, a bit insecure after all the hectic this afternoon.
   Until this afternoon the server default booted on kernel 1 which I suppose is the former Xenial?
2. When logon I see this message:

```
New release '18.04.6 LTS' available. Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it
```

But when I enter lsb_release -a I got this:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic"
```

Is this repairable? Can I try to finish the Bionic upgrade (2nd kernel) or is this the first sign of a totally unstable server and a lot of trouble?

2. Did not check yet but I guess the first kernel will be the troubled one? Or is that a proper working Xenial still?
3. When I manage to rescue this server to run Bionic properly, can I just delete this "old" kernel or can only old kernels of the same release be thrown away?
4. And if I can delete that "old" first kernel, will the now second one be the first one and do I need to change back my Grub settings to get a proper booting server? I do think so, but I really got a bit scared this afternoon. I have to admit that I still have to learn an awful lot about Ubuntu and the more I learn the more I have to recognize that I am still a beginner...

Thanks for thinking along, advice and justified comments and kind regards,

Aad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I was able to figure out that the release upgrade did not crash but was waiting, so the following commands (described on multiple Ubuntu related forums) did the trick and the server is running successfully with Bionic now:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

$ sudo apt --fix-missing update
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt install -f

$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
$ sudo update-grub

$ sudo reboot
```

So problem solved, question closed.

Kind regards,

Aad Dijksman

Comment: Well done. Not newbie stuff Aad. Well researched and therefor +1. Now you can accept your own answer by ticking the V shaped sign ( takes 2 days to be able to do that ). You get 15 rep points for that if I'm correct.

Comment: Thanks Joepie Es.